# Dashboard Sharing from Tenable Security Centre to an External User

Tags: security, user-controls, dashboard, sharing, nessus

Is there any way to share dashboards from tenable to an external user mail id?

I've tried in many ways but ended up finding solution for sharing it to the Groups with internal users.

Appreciate your prompt response for my query.